# iOS linking to "ABAddressBook.h"

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, ios4

So I suspect this to be a project problem as opposed to a code problem.  I am still relatively new to xcode.  I am trying to access the ABAddressBook libraries and have included them in the project alright.

![alt text][1][1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lBaW0.png

Now when I try to say import "ABAddressBook.h", it doesn't know what I am talking about.  Is there anything else I need to do to get that set up?  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
#import <AddressBook/AddressBook.h>
#import <AddressBookUI/AddressBookUI.h>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to import two frameworks one is the

AddressBook and the other is AddressBookUI and then you have to import those files into your viewController subclass file and you are done